# ArrayFire GFOR loop unexpected errors

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl, arrayfire

I am trying to use the GFOR construct, but I can't even make it work for basic stuff.

I suspect that the GFOR loop does not work with linear indexes, am I correct?

Here are some code samples that don't work

```
af::array x(100, 200);
af::array y(100, 200);
af::array xx(100, 200);
gfor(af::seq i, (100 * 200)) {
    xx(i) = x(i) + y(i);
}
```

This one is supposed to do a simple addition element-wise (I know I can just do xx = x+y, I just want to show that gfor is not working as expected). The error is
Invalid input size:203 in function seqToDims.

Another one is a more simple program, like this

```
af::array x(100, 200);
af::array y(100, 200);
gfor(af::seq i, (100 * 200)) {
    y(i) = x(i) + 1;
}
```

Same error.

I have seen the documentation and what I think is that gfor does not work with linear indexes and I need to somehow work "line-by-line" or "column-by-column", because the examples in the docs always show something like A(span,i) and not A(i).

Apart from that, what I really want to do is something simple:
I have:
an array image(rows,cols), 
an array x_(8, rows*cols),
an array ax(8,1);
and a scalar which is found by sum(x_(span,i)*ax) 
(it's actually the dot product, but the dot() function is not supported in gfor), this scalar is computed by using the columns of x_ (size of 8) and the ax which is of size 8 too.

I want

```
e(i) = image(i) - sum<float>(ax * x_(span,i));
```

I can't seem to make it work because not even the simple gfor loops above work, which is unexpected, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question, I have not managed to make gfor work for anything. not even the example on the docs (ie A = A+1).

Answer (score 0):

You have declared 2-dimensional arrays, but you are trying to address them with only one dimension. You cannot have

```
array x(100, 200);
x(150) = 10;   // The second dimension is missing here.
```

You can use gfor to create a sequence and use this sequence in one of the dimensions. You can use the usual ways to address the other dimension, i.e. 'span'.

```
array x(100, 200); // 100 columns, 200 rows
gfor (seq i, 200) {   // will create a sequence from 0...199
   x(span, i) += 10;  // will take a slice of x: the entire column (span) of row 'i'
                      // and add the value 10 to it
}
```

Note that `x` is now being addressed with two dimensions? The first dimension is `span`, in other words, the entire span of that dimension. The second dimension is the sequence defined in `gfor`. You can of course swap the dimensions:

```
array x(100, 200); // same as above
gfor (seq i, 100) {  // create  a sequence from 0..99  (not 199)
   x(i, span) += 20; // access x by rows (span) and the sequence i
}
```

From your code I can deduct that you are still thinking linearly/sequentially, like a C(++) programmer. The giveaway is `seq i, (100*200)` You are trying to iterate over the entire elements (rows*cols), but arrayfire uses vector arithmetics. You do not want to access individual elements. You want to access vectors/slices/entire rows or colums and do something with them.

And for what you are actually trying to acomplish (`e(i) = image(i)...`) have a look at the arrayfire batch function. This might help.